# Multiple Refresh Requests Yields Self-Removing LocalStorage Items in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, local-storage

Today, I came up with an issue which yields localstorage to crash.

I have `username` and `password` credentials stored in `localstorage`. When user refreshes the page, system programatically logins by using these credentials stored in `localstorage`.

But when user spams refresh button for 4 or 5 times(without letting page to be loaded), `localstorage` remove credentials.

To solve this problem, I've added breakpoints in every `localstorage.removeItem` to see if I delete this credentials by mistake, but non of them executed.

So my question is, is there any other way to remove `localstorage`'s credentials or am I facing with some kind of bug?

I'm using Google Chrome v35.0.1916.153.

Thanks.

Comment: Post some code with your question and Do a test, right click on the page and choose inspect element. Click on Console and type localStorage  -- what do you see data wise?? keep redressing the page

Comment: Since there is complicated implementation, I couldn't really sure about passing that much code to here. I guess I simply described the question. When I watch the localStorage, I see `object` and `localStorage.username`, `localStorage.password` gives true credentials. But the credentials suddenly becomes `null` after spamming refresh. `localStorage` stays as `object`.

Comment: Ok fair enough. I had a similar issue with my local storage items going null and eventually i traced down to the script running too fast, so i used an asynchronous function to slow it down when reading local storage items. That's whats probably happening, its running too fast